# fullcalendar select callback not firing in mobile

Tags: jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar, ui-calendar

I am using [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) version 2.9.1. I am rendering calendar as **agendaWeek**. When I click on specific time slot from desktop, it's firing the select callback, but when I click on the mobile device it's not. What is the problem?

```
     selectable:true,
     select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
      // event is firing this callback
     }
```

I am using this in angular application using **[ui.calendar](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to tap and hold in order to select dates/slots in mobile devices... https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/longPressDelay/

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you need to set the click time.

`longPressDelay: 1`

example

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar
  height: 'auto'
  nowIndicator: true
  defaultView: gon.default_view
  header: ''
  selectable: true
  selectHelper: true
  longPressDelay: 1
  selectConstraint:
    start: '00:00'
    end: '24:00'
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is looking for the same in React and stumbles in this post, like it happened to me, you can do it like the code bellow be using the `longPressDelay={1}` property.

```
  <FullCalendar
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, listPlugin]}
        headerToolbar={{
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,listWeek', // timeGridWeek,timeGridDay
        }}
        initialView="dayGridMonth"
        editable
        selectable
        selectMirror
        dayMaxEvents
        weekends
        initialEvents={testEvents}
        select={handleDateSelect}
        eventClick={handleEventClick}
        themeSystem="bootstrap5"
        longPressDelay={1} // This is the property you need to change
      />
```